# substituting third occurrence of a pattern using sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Here is a `sed` command. I want to substitute third occurrence of `00` to `11`

```
echo "0000000000000000" | sed -e 's/00/11/3'
```

The output is:

```
0000110000000000
```

But I thought output would be:

```
0011000000000000
```

first occurrence of `00`:

```
{00}00000000000000
```

second one:

```
0{00}0000000000000
```

and third one:

```
00{00}000000000000
```

Can someone explain what is  happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a `sed` regex pattern has been matched, its next search starts from immediately *after* the just matched pattern...  To do what you want, you need something like `perl`'s regex [Look-Ahead and Look-Behind Zero-width Assertions](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444).

In your case, you want to assert (check) that a sub-pattern (the *2nd* `0`) does exist after the *1st* `0` of your overall-pattern.  The *sub-pattern* is treated as having zero-width, and so when the overall-pattern is matched, the search continues from immediately after the *1st* part of the pattern, namely, after your first zero `0`.